# PHP string larger than 2048 charatcter turns tu null

Tags: php, string, string-length

In contradiction with the documentation, in the following cycle (I am creating a select) when the variable `$retval` reaches 2048 characters, it's set to `null`.

```
    foreach ($cache_ecmcategories as $category) {
        $retval.= '<option value="'.$category['rowid'].'"';
        if (($isfilter ? $category['label'] : $category['rowid']) == $defaulttx)
            $retval.= ' selected="selected"';
        $retval.= '>'.$category['label'].'</option>'; <== This line generate the problem
    }
```

Also, change the PHP version from 5.6.25 to 7.0.10, the problem remains the same

What is the cause of this strange behavior?

Comment: Whats your memorysize?

Comment: What does your php error_log say ? I have an option longer than 2048 and it works.

Comment: In contradiction with *what part of the* documentation exactly?

Comment: I read that strings can goes up to 2GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue on my server with the following script:

```php
<?php
$foo='';
for($i=0; $i < 1000; $i++) $foo .= "cur:$i ";
var_dump($foo);
```

Even an additional `$foo .= NULL;` doesn't trigger the bug for me.
Are you really sure that the bug happens on your posted code? Have you tried to add additional debug statements?

Comment: IMHO - this should be a comment as it is asking for clarification.

Comment: Yes I'm sure, because I use a line by line debugger. I did deeper test and I can say that the error (string to null) came when I add the 2049 char.